# Regex; Stop username containing sysmbols?

Tags: php, regex

I'm looking a symbol regex in PHP that will check submitted usernames and reject them if they contain symbols other than an underscore? I want it to also support numbers also.

I have no idea where to start with it... I've tried looking online but to no prevail. Thanks in advance. If you could give me a push in the right direction I'd appreciate it hugely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/^\w+$/
```

In PHP:

```
echo preg_match('/^\w+$/',$username);
```

I encourage you to learn [Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

**Note:** If you weren't including the underscore, I would suggest [`ctype_alnum()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.ctype-alnum.php) and avoid Regular Expressions.

Comment: That will accept any string which contains at least one digit or word character (since digits are word characters, the `\d` is redundant) .

Answer (score 0):

This is the Regex you are looking for:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9_]+$/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function validate($str){
   return preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\_]/", "", $str);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want accept only Alphanumeric you can use this /^[A-z0-9_]+$/

Use:

```
$pattern_char = /^[A-z0-9_]+$/;

if(preg_match($pattern_char ,$_POST['newname'])
{
// do stuff
}
```

Hope it help

Answer (score 0):

```
 ^[a-z0-9_]{3,20}$
```

this is the way I did it in java , hope yo don't mind numbers 
and I defined a length as well,

Answer (score 0):

I'd say:

```
preg_match('/^[\pL\pN_]+$/u', $string);
```

where:

```
\pL  stands for any letter
\pN  stands for any digit
```